# Foreach php function inside HTML select options

Tags: php, html

Im a newbie to this forum and have just started coding in php. Need some help. I have the following code

```
<?php error_reporting(-1);

require_once('/mysql/sql_connect.php');

$q = "SELECT pty.pty_profile_name AS profile FROM pty, users WHERE users.username = 'testaccount' ";
    $r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);

    $results_array = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {
        array_push($results_array, $row);
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($results_array); echo "</pre>"; }

?>

<p>
<form method="post" action="foreach2.php">
<label for="Property Select" class="title">Select Property</label>  
   <select name="pty_select" > 
   <?php foreach($results_array as $key => $value){ ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $value['profile']; ?></option> 
    <?php } ?>
        </select>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" />
</form>

<?php 

if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
echo "<pre>"; echo ($_POST['pty_select']); echo "</pre>"; } ?>
```

The output I get is correct, but it displays the key, eg, 0 or 1 or 2, based on what I select in the form. I need the value output. Eg `0 = Emerton`, it outputs "0" instead of `Emerton`.

If I echo `$value['profile']` instead of `pty_select`, I get the last result of the query all the time. Which in this example would be 2, which is `Ambarvale` as I believe it just chooses the last row output of the query.

I hope I've made sense. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean you need the value what you have used to display it.
Then,
Change to :

```
<option value="<?php echo $value['profile']; ?>">
    <?php echo $value['profile']; ?>
</option>
```

Comment: thanks that worked. Just waiting on a response from another poster before closing

Answer (score 5):

It will obviously echo the key, as you assigned the value of options as `$key`
if you need the options in the `$_POST['pty_select']` use this:

```
 <select name="pty_select" > 
<?php foreach($results_array as $key => $value){ ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $value['profile'];?>"><?php echo $value['profile'];     ?></option> 
<?php } ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: thanks that worked. Just waiting on a response from another poster before closing

Answer (score 2):

Give

```
<option value="<?php echo $value['profile']; ?>"><?php echo $value['profile']; ?></option>
```

instead of

```
<option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $value['profile']; ?></option>
```

Comment: thanks that worked. Just waiting on a response from another poster before closing

Comment: @DanielGarcia please close once you are done. Cheers and Happy Coding. :)

Comment: Hi, how do I close again? Sorry I am new to this site

Comment: @DanielGarcia their is a tick mark you would see below the vote symbol near answer just tick it. Then it will be marked as solved.

Answer (score 2):

And now let's go to ideal world :)

Build data pairs `database_id => name` for options:

```
$q = "SELECT pty.id, pty.pty_profile_name AS profile FROM pty, users 
      WHERE users.username = 'testaccount'";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

$values = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_row($r)) {
    $values[$r[0]] = $r[1];
}
```

Never use `@` when working with database, why do you want to suppress errors instead of preventing/handling them?

Now you have real database IDs and respective values (in general, using unique IDs are better... if nothing else they have greater entropy - more efficient search). And sice displaying select box is really common in webs, lets:

```
function selectbox( $values = array(), $attributes = array(), $selected_value = null)
{
    // Header
    echo '<select';
    foreach( $attributes as $key => $val){
        echo ' ' . htmlspecialchars($key) . '="' . htmlspecialchars( $val) . '"';
    }
    echo '>';

    // Values
    foreach( $values as $key => $val){
        echo '<option value="' . htmlspecialchars( $key) .'"';
        if( $key === $selected_value){
            echo ' selected="selected"';
        }
        echo '>' . htmlspecialchars( $val) . '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
}
```

And now usage :)

```
<form method="post" action="foreach2.php">
<label for="Property Select" class="title">Select Property</label>  
    <?php selectbox( $values, array( 'name' => 'pty_select')); ?>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" />
</form>
```

And what to do with it then?

```
$id = (int)(isset( $_POST['pty_select']) ? $_POST['pty_select'] : 0);
$name = null;
if( $id && isset( $values[$id])){
    $name = $values[$id];
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys I will try these suggestions tonight and let you know how I get on. Cheers

Comment: Hi Vyktor, the code that the others gave me worked, however, I am trying to figure out how to get your code working as I want to learn new techiques. What does  $values[$r[0]] = $r[1]; do? Why would the 2nd value in an array need to be assigned to the first value?

Comment: @DanielGarcia idea is you'll get pairs `(id,name)` pairs like `(1, Emerton)` or `(2,Foo)`. Note those are real database ids. And you'll build associative array `$values = array( 1=>"Emerton", 2=>"Foo")` and you can use it as `$values[1]` to get string. IDs are universal identifiers which are effective and therefore I prefer to use them :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
echo "<pre>"; echo ($_POST['pty_select']); echo "</pre>"; } ?>
```

Change it to something like

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    echo $results_array[$_POST['pty_select']]['profile'];
}
```

Or alternatively use profile option value.