# PHP add options to <select multiple></select>

Tags: php, mysql

Just want to ask if it is possible to use PHP in my question so here it is. I am making a simple search code wherein the user will search for example "John" now many John's will appear on a table. In each row there will be a button named "add to list". If the user clicks the add button, the details of John will be put inside the select multiple like this.

```
<select multiple class="form-control">
    <option>John</option>
</select>
```

now if I click another for example "Kevin" it will become...

```
<select multiple class="form-control">
    <option>John</option>
    <option>Kevin</option>
</select>
```

once the select multiple has been populated I will print it(thats another story now). So basically my question is how do I add values to `<select multiple>` by pressing the button "add" and get the ID's of the options inside select multiple for retrieval? I think i'm making my question complicated and i'm very sorry for my bad english. I've tried if, for, do-while, while but i cant seem to get the logic.I hope you understand thank you very much!

Comment: its going to be ajax if you really want this apporach

Comment: you can use `arrays` to store result and then populate dropdown from arrays

Comment: yep, `foreach` ought to get you going. Remember to name that select of yours and give values to your options.

Comment: @Dagon Is it really necessary? because i have no idea about that and i'm almost done and i'm so frustrated already hahahah.

Comment: @Fred-ii- can you give me an idea on how to start foreach because I don't even know how to start it. I can easily use it to retrieve data from the database but I dont know how I can manipulate the data to go inside the <option></option>

Comment: here's a quick q&a http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479999/foreach-value-from-post-from-form then Google "foreach POST php" for more results. Edit: Here's another http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16034281/foreach-php-function-inside-html-select-options

Comment: for extracting the data from database use foreach() loop and. In order to auto filter your data like if you search for "JOHN".. USE the jqueryui autocomplete libarry -> https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/. Then after gettin  your data u need ajax to pull that data to your select form.

Comment: This seems like an odd user interface. How are the candidates selected in the first place? Are they typed into an autosuggest text box?

Comment: @Strawberry its like.. I search in a textbox, results come out in a table, each row has a button, so if there are 10 results there will be 10 buttons which means 1 button is assigned to 1 result. and if i press that button the corresponding result will be put inside the select multiple

Comment: What is the structure of your table? And schema? Could you also include the other code you are using for searching?

Comment: But why? Why not just leave them in the checkbox select?

Comment: I don't think you need ajax here as you already fetched the users and show them in the table. You can add data field with ID to the button or put the ID as an argument in js function or put it in a hidden div and add select option after getting the ID from the element/argument/data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) so the page won't have to reload when a name/button is clicked/select.

Example code:

```
<!-- HERE ARE THE LIST OF NAMES TO BE ADDED IN THE SELECT FIELD -->
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Kevin</td>
        <td><button class="names" value="Kevin">Add to List</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>John</td>
         <td><button class="names" value="John">Add to List</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<!-- AND HERE IS THE SELECT FIELD THAT YOU WANT TO BE POPULATED -->
<select multiple class="form-control" id="select-names">
    <option disabled selected>Select first from the table of names</option>
</select>
```

And we have to create a script that when a button is selected, it will be added to the `<select>` field. You have to download first jQuery [here](https://jquery.com/download/).

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> <!-- REPLACE NECESSARY FILE DEPENDING ON THE VERSION OF jQuery YOU HAVE DOWNLOADED -->
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){ /* PREPARE THE SCRIPT */
    $(".names").click(function(){ /* WHEN A BUTTON IS CLICKED */
        var names = $(this).val(); /* GET THE VALUE OF THAT BUTTON */
        $(this).closest("tr").fadeOut(200).hide(); /* HIDE THIS ROW */

        var newOption = $('<option></option>'); /* CREATE AN OPTION */
        newOption.val(names); /* SET THE VALUE OF THIS OPTION WITH THE VALUE OF THE SELECTED NAME */
        newOption.html(names); /* SET THE CONTENT OF THIS OPTION */
        $("#select-names").append(newOption); /* APPEND THIS OPTION TO THE SELECT FIELD */

    });
  });

</script>
```

If you want a proof, check this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9s54tm5u/1/).

But if you also want a database interaction, post your database structure, explain the schema and give us more of the code you are working on.